# Standard library function objects and unrelated pointer comparison

Tags: c++, stl

I came across this while going through *C++ Primer 5th edition*

> The standard library defines a set of classes that represent the arithmetic, relational, and logical operators.
>
> One important aspect of these library function objects is **that the library guarantees that they will work for pointers**. Recall that comparing two unrelated pointers is undefined (§ 3.5.3, p. 120). However, we might want to sort a vector of pointers based on their addresses in memory. Although it would be undefined for us to do so directly, we can do so through one of the library function objects:

I can't help but wonder, **how does it get rid of the undefined behavior?** My guess is maybe a cast to some type big enough to hold the address then compare. Or is something else at play here?

Comment: The standard library implementation can (in fact, sometimes must) take advantage of the implementation details of the particular compiler it is designed to work with. It doesn't have to (in fact, generally cannot) be implemented entirely in standard-conforming portable C++.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare unrelated pointers directly, but you can cast them to the long enough unsigned integer type and the compare results. It's OK. Example from GCC

```
  template<typename _Tp>
    struct less<_Tp*> : public binary_function<_Tp*, _Tp*, bool>
    {
      _GLIBCXX14_CONSTEXPR bool
      operator()(_Tp* __x, _Tp* __y) const _GLIBCXX_NOTHROW
      {
#if __cplusplus >= 201402L
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_BUILTIN_IS_CONSTANT_EVALUATED
    if (__builtin_is_constant_evaluated())
#else
    if (__builtin_constant_p(__x < __y))
#endif
      return __x < __y;
#endif
    return (__UINTPTR_TYPE__)__x < (__UINTPTR_TYPE__)__y;
      }
    };
```

Comment: ... until you have to build for an architecture with [segmented memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I am confused about the semantics of pointer comparison. We are comparing the virtual address values right? If comparing virtual addresses, would segmented memory architecture still be an issue?

Comment: It is not specified exactly how `std::less<T*>` is to compare two pointers. The standard only guarantees that it establishes a total order (any two pointers can be compared), and this order is consistent with built-in operator `<` (that is, for pointers into the same array, `p1 < p2` and `std::less<T*>()(p1, p2)` would produce the same result). The rest is internal implementation detail.

Comment: I think if you cast to a pointer of size at least `std::intptr_t` you should be fine because that number is traceable (6.6.4.4.3), and you can convert it back to a pointer and get the same object. So, two different pointers casted to `intptr_t` cannot be the same, and integral types are comparable. The thing is that `intptr_t` is optional, and if it does not exist, I think you cannot compare the two pointers.

Comment: I.e., if `intptr_t` exists, you can implement `operator<` for pointers yourself, if it does not exist, then probably you can't.

Comment: @overseas I recall that, [in 16-bit x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model), it was possible to have multiple distinct address representations for the same memory location. Just naively casting a pointer to a large integer would not have produced a total order; additional care had to be taken to normalize the address to a canonical representation (look for "huge pointer" in that article).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  I see your point, and thanks for the link, but isn't this exactly the reason why one wouldn't have a `intptr_t` on that system? That pointer would not be traceable as an integer, and you cannot convert it back and forth between pointer and integer, which is what this "integer representation of a safely-derived pointer" is about, see http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic#def:safely-derived_pointer,integer_representation

Comment: @overseas Perhaps. I must admit I have no idea whether there exist standard-conforming compilers capable of building for 16-bit x86, or whether their standard library defines `intptr_t`. When I last worked on that platform, the C++ standard didn't exist yet; neither did `intptr_t`.